# Best way to implement grid with many columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2, user-experience

I would like your opinion / knowledge about a situation I have:

I have a Mysql table with approximately 50 columns (where the user can filter whether or not the client has multiple products, etc). And currently I only display 10 columns, and the other filter options are optional.

I would like a way to display as many columns as possible so that users can perform the desired filters (they are accustomed to filtering in Excel).

I had thought about leaving the Associated column always visible, and the others with horizontal scrollbars, what do you think? It's possible?

Current Grid:

[image]

Comment: are you saying that you want the user to selected which columns to show on runtime and which not?

Comment: That would be an option too.
I think a horizontal scroll bar is a valid option either .. or split into tabs,

Comment: i would try something like hiding the columns by default using css and provide a checkbox list with those column names on top of the gridview and then on selecting any of the checkboxes the selected columns will show or hide using javascript , that way you can avoid a horizontal scroll bar too which annoys the user and at the same time add columns to the filter

Comment: For a column, create a **collapse**, put multiple field data in it.

Comment: @user206 I did not understand very well, can you give me some example for me to see?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I like your suggestion, I think it looks better than a horizontal scroll bar

Comment: **primarily opinion-based** - Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I put a post. But according to the view of the master dear @Rob, I have not fully understood your question. I have not considered filtering. The only space was created for inserting more columns.
So I deleted the post. Accept my apology

Comment: You can try to build table with a fixed first column. Here is an example: https://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/gWoVzN

Comment: @WeSee Yes , it was exactly this example I found and intend to draw on. I will also try adding a scroll bar so users can view all customer products