# Yii2 : Gridview with fixed first column

Tags: gridview, twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2

Can someone help me to implement a Gridview (Yii2) where the first column (NAME) was always visible and the others I could scroll horizontally to the side.

My customers asked for an Excel-like interface where they could view and filter various customer information (various products marked YES or NO).

At first, I have this example as a reference:

**REF 1 from bootsnip**

```css
.scrolling table {
  table-layout: inherit;
  *margin-left: -100px;
  /*ie7*/
}

.scrolling td,
th {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.scrolling th {
  position: absolute;
  *position: relative;
  /*ie7*/
  left: 0;
  width: 120px;
}

.outer {
  position: relative
}

.inner {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: visible;
  margin-left: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Forms</a></li>
        <li class="active">Edit</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-9">
      <div class="scrolling outer">
        <div class="inner">
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
            <tr>
              <th>Date:</th>
              <td>Content One</td>
              <td>Longer Content Two</td>
              <td>Third Content Contains More</td>
              <td>Short Four</td>
              <td>Standard Five</td>
              <td>Who's Counting</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th><input type="text" class="form-control" value="03-03-2008"></th>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="22"></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="22"></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="22"></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="22"></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="22"></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="22"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th><input type="text" class="form-control" value="07-05-2009"></th>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="23"></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="23"></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="23"></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="23"></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="23"></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="23"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th><input type="text" class="form-control" value="17-06-2010"></th>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="24"></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="24"></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="24"></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="24"></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="24"></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="24"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th><input type="text" class="form-control" value="05-07-2011"></th>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="25"></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="25"></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="25"></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="25"></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="25"></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="25"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th><input type="text" class="form-control" value="09-08-2012"></th>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="26"></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="26"></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="26"></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="26"></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="26"></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="26"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-3">
      <div class="well">
        <p class="text-danger">Shrink your browser window to see the scroll bar apear as content overflows to the right</p>
        <p>Left Column (th) stays fixed</p>
        <p>Anytime there is too much content to the right the scroll bar will appear.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**REF 2 from codepen**

```js
// requires jquery library
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".main-table").clone(true).appendTo('#table-scroll').addClass('clone');
});
```

```css
.table-scroll {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.table-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.table-scroll table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.table-scroll th,
.table-scroll td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.table-scroll thead,
.table-scroll tfoot {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

.clone {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.clone th,
.clone td {
  visibility: hidden
}

.clone td,
.clone th {
  border-color: transparent
}

.clone tbody th {
  visibility: visible;
  color: red;
}

.clone .fixed-side {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #eee;
  visibility: visible;
}

.clone thead,
.clone tfoot {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table-scroll" class="table-scroll">
  <div class="table-wrap">
    <table class="main-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 2</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 3</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 4</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 5</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 6</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 7</th>
          <th scope="col">Header 8</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content<br> test
          </td>
          <td><a href="#">Cell content longer</a></td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">Left Column</th>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content longer</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side">&nbsp;</th>
          <td>Footer 2</td>
          <td>Footer 3</td>
          <td>Footer 4</td>
          <td>Footer 5</td>
          <td>Footer 6</td>
          <td>Footer 7</td>
          <td>Footer 8</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<p>See <a href="https://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/LBrMxa" target="blank">position Sticky version </a>with no JS</p>
```

My gridview: [Best way to implement grid with many columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57146947/best-way-to-implement-grid-with-many-columns)

**UPDATE**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think its that hard to implement it all you need to do is to carefully watch

- CSS class & properties
- The html structure to follow
- Update/add the classes you need to add depending on your requirements
- Add `!important` for the properties that are overridden by the theme or the bootstrap.

i will implement the first example in your question into the gridview all you have to do is top copy the following css on top of your view, i have added a few selectors which are necessary to work with grid view and they target the column Heading and the filter input too.

**Note: i have tested the following example with the default Yii2 setup that comes with the bootstrap and jquery versions that are used in the 1st example above.**

```
$this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
    $css = <<<CSS
    .scrolling table {
  table-layout: inherit !important;
  *margin-left: -100px !important;
  /*ie7*/
}

.scrolling td,
th {
  vertical-align: top !important;
  padding: 10px !important;
  min-width: 100px !important;
}

.scrolling thead th:first-child,
.scrolling thead tr.filters td:first-child,
.scrolling tbody td:first-child {
  position: absolute !important;
  *position:relative !important;
  /*ie7*/
  left: 0 !important;
  width: 120px !important;
}

.outer {
  position: relative !important;
}

.inner {
  overflow-x: auto !important;
  overflow-y: visible !important;
  margin-left: 120px !important;
}

CSS;
    $this->registerCss($css);
```

Then you need to wrap your `GridView` inside the `<div class="scrolling outer">` and your gridview should have these properties defined

- Add the class to the default wrapper div created by gridview

  ```
  'options' => ['class' => 'inner']`.
  ```
- Override the table classes to remove the `table-bordered` class which disturbs the layout of the table,

  ```
   'tableOptions' => ['class' => 'table table-striped table-hover table-condensed']`
  ```

So your GridView code will look like below

```
<div class="scrolling outer">
    <?php echo GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'options' => ['class' => 'inner'],
            'tableOptions' => ['class' => 'table table-striped table-hover table-condensed'],
            'columns' => [
                'name',
                ....
                //Your rest of the columns
                ....
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                ]
            ]
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

Remember whichever column you will specify as the first in your grid view, will be docked to the left, in your case it should be `name`.

If you did everything correctly your `GridView` will look like below, you can notice the first column `Name` docked at the left and the scrolled section from the scroll bar.

[image]

Comment: It's almost there! How do I increase the width of the first column? 
'style' => 'width: 150px'; does not work

Comment: Omer,  See my UPDATE

Comment: @gugoan , you are not paying attention, well, change the `width:120px` in the `.scrolling thead th:first-child,
.scrolling thead tr.filters td:first-child,
.scrolling tbody td:first-child`, and then `margin:120px` in the `.inner`

Comment: Ok, I get it. It worked right here. I just need to make some visual formatting adjustments.