# Yii2 Gridview - Horizontal Top Scroll Bar

Tags: css, gridview, yii2

I'm using a Gridview building with the help of this post [Yii2 : Gridview with fixed first column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57277613/yii2-gridview-with-fixed-first-column), and would like to include a horizontal scrollbar at the top of the grid.

My users liked the ability to display multiple columns on the same screen, but it wasn't cool to scroll down to the bottom to scroll right.

Can someone help me implement a horizontal scrollbar on top of this grid? I tried to follow some tutorials but had no success.

**My Gridview**

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\models\Location;
use app\models\User;
use app\modules\client\models\Painel;
use app\modules\client\models\PainelSearch;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use kartik\date\DatePicker;

$this->title = 'Painel';
?>

<style>
.scrolling table {
  table-layout: inherit !important;
  *margin-left: -100px !important;
  /*ie7*/
}

.scrolling td,
th {
  vertical-align: top !important;
  padding: 10px !important;
  min-width: 100px !important;
}

.scrolling thead th:first-child,
.scrolling thead tr.filters td:first-child,
.scrolling tbody td:first-child {
  position: absolute !important;
  *position:relative !important;
  /*ie7*/
  left: 0 !important;
  width: 380px !important;
  border-color: #DBDBBE;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 3px;
}

.outer {
  position: relative !important;
}

.inner {
  overflow-x: auto !important;
  overflow-y: visible !important;
  margin-left: 380px !important;
}


</style>

<div class="painel-index">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
    <?php
    $contentOptions = ['class' => 'text-center', 'style'=>'width: 3%;text-align:center;vertical-align: middle'];
    $headerOptions  = ['style'=>'width:1px;word-wrap: break-word;white-space:pre-wrap;text-align:center;vertical-align: middle;background-color: #D7DE36;border: 0'];
    ?>

    <div class="scrolling outer" style="font-size:12px;">
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'options' => ['class' => 'inner'],
        'tableOptions' => ['class' => 'table table-striped table-hover table-bordered'],
        'formatter'     => ['class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter','nullDisplay' => '<span class="not-set">--</span>'],
        'columns' => [
            [
                'attribute' => 'namecpfcnpj',
                'encodeLabel' => false,
                'format' => 'raw',  
                'label' => 'Nome<br/> Associado',
                'value' => function ($model) {
                    return  Html::a('<b>'.$model->client_nome.'</b>', ['view', 'id' => $model->id]) .
                    Html::a('<i class="fas fa-chart-pie"></i> APN', ['printapn', 'id' => $model->client_num_cpfcnpj], ['target'=>'_blank','class'=>'btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right', 'style'=>'margin-left:2px', 'title' => 'Clique para abrir o APN desse associado']);
                    },
                'filterInputOptions' => [
                    'class'       => 'form-control',
                    'placeholder' => 'Pesquise Nome ou CPF/CNPJ',
                    ],
                'contentOptions' => ['style'=>'width: 15%;text-align:left;vertical-align: middle;font-weight: bold;text-transform: uppercase;background-color: #DBDBBE;'],
                'headerOptions'  => ['style'=>'text-align:center;vertical-align: middle;background-color: #D7DE36;'],
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'client_num_pa',
                'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Location::find()->orderBy('num_sisbr')->asArray()->all(), 'num_sisbr', 'shortname'),
                'contentOptions' => $contentOptions,
                'headerOptions'  => $headerOptions,
            ],
            'prod_captacao_remunerada_rdc',
            'prod_captacao_remunerada_lca',
            'prod_poupanca',
            'prod_cartao_credito_ativo',
            'prod_cartao_debito_ativo',
            'prod_cobranca',
            'prod_consorcio_automovel',
            'prod_consorcio_imovel',
            'prod_consorcio_servico',
            'prod_consorcio_moto',
            'prod_pacote_tarifas',
            'prod_emprestimo',
            'prod_financiamento',
            'prod_titulos_descontados',
            'prod_credito_rural',
            'prod_pre_aprovado',
            'prod_cheque_especial',
            'prod_previdencia',
            'prod_seguro_agronegocio_nao_parceira',
            'prod_seguro_agronegocio_parceira',
            'prod_seguro_automovel_nao_parceira',
            'prod_seguro_automovel_parceira',
            'prod_seguro_gerais_nao_parceira',
            'prod_seguro_gerais_parceira',
            'prod_seguro_prestamista',
            'prod_seguro_previ_outras_seg',
            'prod_seguro_previ_sicoob_seg',
            'prod_seguro_res_emp_nao_parceira',
            'prod_seguro_res_emp_parceira',
            'prod_seguro_vida_pfpj_outras_seg',
            'prod_seguro_vida_pfpj_sicoob_seg',
            'prod_debito_automatico',
            'prod_conta_garantida',
        ],
    ]); ?>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: **horizontal scroll bar on top** wont help understanding the  layout you are trying to follow as a simeple overflow-y will do that but you need a specific styling and UX which isnt in a simple scroll so show the example you  are trying to implement or follow

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam A simple examples that would help me would be this: http://jsfiddle.net/TBnqw/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two scrolls up and down.

**Add the following CSS codes:**

```
.scrolltop {
  overflow-y:hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 380px !important;
  height: 20px;
}

.scrolltop div {
  width:1000px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: -100px !important;
}
```

**Insert the following html code into the scrolling outer:**

```
<div class="scrolling outer" style="font-size:12px;">
<!-- Add the following parts of -->
<div class='scrolltop'>
  <div></div>
</div>
<!-- Grid... -->
```

**JS Code (jQuery):**

```
  $('.scrolltop').width( $('.inner').width() );
  $('.scrolltop div').width( $('.table').width() );

  $(".scrolltop").scroll(function(){
    $(".inner").scrollLeft($(".scrolltop").scrollLeft());
  });
  $(".inner").scroll(function(){
    $(".scrolltop").scrollLeft($(".inner").scrollLeft());
  });
```

---

(**Optional**) You can add the following as well:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('.scrolltop').width( $('.inner').width() );
  $('.scrolltop div').width( $('.table').width() );
});
```